# Replace a piece of text with both the text and the thing to be replaced Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to replace a text that has a start and an end with the text itself and a label:

```
def replace_at(label, start, end, txt):
    """Replace substring of txt from start to end with label"""
    return ''.join((txt[:start], label, txt[end:]))
```

In this way, I get the label in place of the text but would like the text too. So the current output for "Hi my name is", with name that is labelled, is:

```
Hi my LABEL is
```

And I would like

```
Hi my name LABEL is
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I don’t see a question, only a series of statements.

Comment: It depends on how you call the function, and that call is missing in your question. For me it works with `replace_at("LABEL",11,10,"Hi my name is")`

Comment: "In this way, I get the label in place of the text but would like the text too" Okay, so your approach is to take: everything before the original text; the replacement; and everything after the original text - and stick those things together. Right? Can you think of something else you could add to that group of things, in order to get the result you want? Alternately: can you think of a way to modify the "everything after the text" logic so that it includes the original text?

Comment: Alternately: in the desired output, **everything that was in the input** is included, right? We're really just **inserting** something at the `end` point, right? Do we actually care about `start`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your function to achieve the desired result like this:

```
def replace_at(label, start, end, txt):
    """Replace substring of txt from start to end with label"""
    return ''.join((txt[:start], label, txt[end:]))

s = "Hi my name is"
label_text = " LABEL"
final_word = "name"
idx = s.index(final_word) + len(final_word)
print(replace_at(label_text, idx, idx, s))
```

With output:

```
Hi my name LABEL is
```

I used the syntax `xs[3:3] = [1,2]` that will insert `[1,2]` at the index 3.

Comment: I call it like  text = replace_at(ent, group['start'], group['end'], text) but it only replaces it

Comment: @Idkwhatywantmed the way to get the correct result is using the `group['end']` twice